# Handle DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected character

Tags: java, json, spring, parsing, error-logging

I'm getting the follow error message

```
WARN 13712 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: 
JSON parse error: Unexpected character (',' (code 44)): expected a value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (',' (code 44)): expected a value at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1db33478; line: 2, column: 16]
```

I'm using spring framework like this.

```
@GetMapping("/access")
public HashMap<String, Object> getAccess() {
    HashMap<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    ArrayList<Access> list = new ArrayList<Access>();
    BdConector bd = BdConector.getInstance();
    list = bd.getAllAccess();

    if (list != null) {
        response.put("result", "200");
    } else {
        response.put("result", "500");
    }
    response.put("items", list);
    return response;
}
```

I would like to log the json body-content when a parser exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
@ExceptionHandler(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException.class)
        public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException ex) {
            LOG.error("Error parse json " +  ex.getMessage());
            ...
        }
```

Not quite shure how to extract original string which is invalid json, maybe it is in exception's "getMessage()", as I shown. Anyway, you can debug "ex" filed and find how to properly get it.